# apt-add-repository raises an error

Tags: 12.04, apt, python

I’m trying to install JDE (Java Development Environment), but apt-get fails with the following error:

```
me@ubuntu:~/$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
  Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK6 /    JDK7 / JDK8). There are no actual Java files in this PPA. More info: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Debian installation instructions: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java
 Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 99, in run
    self.add_ppa_signing_key(self.ppa_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 132, in add_ppa_signing_key
    tmp_keyring_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 322, in mkdtemp
    name = names.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 141, in next
    letters = [choose(c) for dummy in "123456"]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

So, please can someone tell me, what can I do?

(Sorry for my bad English, I hope you understand)

Comment: I have Ubuntu 13.04, and just added the repo without errors.  Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 3):

actually the problem which is bothering you is a [Ubuntu BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1063350/). Look at the BUG link . In the bug link Comment #4 and comment #11 have some good information for you.

comment #11 have patch too & apply that patch and its approved.

Comment: If you apply the patch, report your finding to the bug report.